# DocumentDb DocumentClient get first 25 documents

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, documentclient

Getting started with Cosmos and document db/sql. Why does this not work?  No error is thrown, that I can see.  There is data that should return.

```
    private const string EndpointUri = "some url";
    private const string PrimaryKey = "somekey";
    private const string DbId = "People";
    private const string CollectionId = "Person";
    private DocumentClient client;

    // GET: api/Person
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
        FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 25, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };



        IQueryable<Person> personQuery = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DbId, CollectionId), queryOptions)
            .Where(f => f.NameFirst != "Andersen");

        List<Person> retVal = new List<Person>();
        retVal = personQuery.ToList();
        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MaxItemCount` is the maximum number of items you will get pack per enumeration operation. It doesn't return the first 25 documents but rather all the documents that match this query in aggregated batches of 25 documents per enumeration.

If you want the top 25 items your code should look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> Get()
{
    this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
    FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };

    var personQuery = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(
        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DbId, CollectionId), queryOptions)
        .Where(f => f.NameFirst != "Andersen").Take(25).AsDocumentQuery();

    List<Person> retVal = new List<Person>();

    while(personQuery.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var results = await personQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Person>();
        retVal.AddRange(results);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Depending on how you index strings in your collection you may also need to set the `EnableScanInQuery` property of the `FeedOptions` object to `true`.

Comment: That does not seem to work.      
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedResponse<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CoreWebApp.Entities.Person>' CoreWebApp \documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\CoreWebApp\CoreWebApp\Api\PersonController.cs 44 Active

Comment: @WouldRatherBuildAMotor I added the mapping type on `ExecuteNextAsync`. Give it a go with the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the top documents as you wanted, using LINQ .Take() is the right way, as Nick mentioned.

Using FeedOptions.MaxItemCount and ExecuteNextAsync is also an alternative. However it may return 0 results as you've observed so that needs to be taken into account. For more details on this, please refer to Aravind's comment on this related question: [ExecuteNextAsync Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866896/executenextasync-not-working/43375930#43375930).